# JpaRepository skips some rows while saving to database

Tags: java, multithreading, hibernate, jpa

I'm making a method that is parsing a large file and saving the results in the database.

The file is 12_500_000 lines long, but at the end, on average, 11_400_000 lines are saved.

I divide it into 10_000 log files and parse them all in 8 threads at the time.

The service that is doing the saving:

```java
@Service
public class RequestService implements InterfaceRequestService {

    private final IRequestRepository repository;

    public RequestService(IRequestRepository repository) {
        this.repository = repository;
    }

    @Transactional
    @Override
    public void saveAll(List<Request> requests) {

        for (Request r: requests) {
            repository.save(r);
        }

    }
}
```

And the interface:

```java
public interface InterfaceRequestService {

    void saveAll(List<Request> requests);
}
```

The class that is doing the saving in a thread:

```java
public class Importer implements Runnable{

    private final IRequestService service;

    int fileNumber;

    public Importer(IRequestService service, int fileNumber) {
        this.service = service;
        this.fileNumber = fileNumber;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            service.saveAll(getRequestListFromFile("segment_directory/Log_segment_"+fileNumber+".txt"));
            try {
                Thread.sleep(10);
            }catch (Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

And the method to get the list of entities from a file:

```
 public List<Request> getRequestListFromFile(String filename) throws IOException {

    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filename));

    List<Request> logs = new ArrayList<>();

    String line;


    while((line = reader.readLine())!=null){
        logs.add(getRequestEntityFromLog(line));
    }
    reader.close();

    return logs;
 }
```

Finally, the method that runs all that:

```
public void scheduledDataSave() throws InterruptedException {
    int availableCores = Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors();
    String directory = "segment_directory";

    int filesInDirectory = Objects.requireNonNull(new File(directory).list()).length;

    ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(availableCores);

    for ( int i = 1 ; i <= filesInDirectory ; i++ ) {
        executorService.submit( new Importer( service, i ) );
        if(  i % 8  == 0 ) {
            System.out.println("Sleeping");
            Thread.sleep( Duration.ofSeconds( 10 ).toMillis() ) ;
        }
    }

    executorService.shutdown();
    executorService.awaitTermination(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
}
```

Is there any reason for skipping some lines?

I run a check that

UPDATE:

Run the files separately, but it's still not saving all the rows.

[image: Code with UncaughtExceptionHandler]

[image: Database row count]

Comment: from the given information, it's hard to find the root cause. have you 1. monitored for exceptions? 2. ran your program for each of the log segments separately?

Comment: (1) Do you have a DB connection pool configured? How many connections? (2) Without even reading your code carefully, the first thing I would recommend is try to use a container-provided async execution facility (3) Try setting an `UncaughtExceptionHandler` to the `ExecutorService` and see what crops up

Comment: @crizzis hey, I added the UncaughtExceptionHandler to the ExecutorService and ran the program for each to the log segment separately, but still only '12210903' logs have been saved(on the last try).
I added the screenshots to the question with details